# How to check in a filename only have A-Z 0-9 a-z - _ and space?

Tags: php, regex

I want to restrict file to alphanumeric only with space allowed.

I have tried:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^_A-Za-z0-9 -.]/', $file['name'])) { //do something }

if (preg_match("/[^_A-Za-z0-9 -.]/", $file['name']) !== true) { //do something }

if (preg_match("/[^_A-Za-z0-9 -.]/", $file['name']) !== false) { //do something }

if (preg_match("/^[_A-Za-z0-9 -.]/", $file['name']) !== false) { //do something }

if (preg_match("/^[_A-Za-z0-9 -.]/", $file['name']) !== true) { //do something }

if (preg_match('/^[-A-Za-z0-9._]+$/i', $file['name']) !== true) { //do somethin }
```

In the first example:

`test.jpg` it's accepted.

`testä.jpg` it's accepted too, but it shouldn't be.

In the second  example:

`test.jpg` isn't accepted, but it should be.

`testä.jpg` isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) for the character class, then match a dot literally and use a character class again specifying which characters you would allow to get a more specific match for a filename.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_ -]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

Start the pattern with an anchor to assert the start of the string `^` (If you use it inside the character class at the start `[^` you are negating the character class and assert the end of the string `$`

If you only want to know if there was a match for the filename containing characters that it should not, you could use:

```
^[\w.-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m56O1d/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/2Jvk0)

For example use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and negating it if you want to know it it did not match.

Your code could look like:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\w.-]+$/i', $filename)) {
```

**Note** the return values of preg_match:

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it
>   does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

Comment: i did try your resolution, but if i use === not working.

Comment: You don't have to use === true or false because the return value of [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is 0 or 1

Comment: I don't know why, but this works:

if (preg_match('/^[-A-Za-z0-9._]+$/i', $file['name']) == false) { // }

Comment: Interessting, PHP Manual say:
Warning

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: @McMannehan If you remove the `===` part and use the if statement checking for a positive scenario you could should work. I don't think that previous line from the comments works. See https://3v4l.org/pLVVg

Comment: i remove the === part to == and it works perfect :-)

Comment: it works, only test is wrong too. The name will have all the time *.jpg or *.png
If the filename don't have *.png or *.jpg or any different than *.jpg or *.png an error before will occur.

Comment: @McMannehan I have updated my answer with a negating example of preg_match.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you to everybody for the fast help.
This:

```
if (preg_match('/^[-A-Za-z0-9._]+$/i', $file['name']) == false) { //do error output }
```

works perfect. Only - _ . a-z A-Z 0-9 accepted in the string.

Yes i am sure. The "Demo" is wrong.
The demo should be like that:

```
$file = ["name" => "test.jpg"];
if (preg_match('/^[-A-Za-z0-9._]+$/i', $file['name']) == false) {
  echo "No Match!";
} else {
echo "match!";
}
```

the preg_match give "FALSE" so "No Match" must be the answer!!!

And who gave a "minus" to my answer :-( 
check the demo first before a "minus".

Comment: omg, of course!!! Watch the demo. preg_match check for "FALSE"!!! What else i have to say!!! The answer "FALSE" means "No Match"!!!